# DateTime format conversion

Tags: c#, datetime

In my c# program, a user can pick a date from a winforms date-time-picker. This is named `dtpOutbox`.

Here is my code:

```
DateTime selectedDate = dtpOutbox.Value.Date;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(23,59,59);
DateTime endOfSelectedDay = selectedDate + ts;

Console.WriteLine(selectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
Console.WriteLine(endOfSelectedDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

Now if todays date is 22nd Feb, it is my understanding that this should output (desired output):

```
2013-02-22 00:00:00
2013-02-22 23:59:59
```

But this is not the case. My output is:

```
2013-02-22 12:00:00
2013-02-22 11:59:59
```

I'm pretty sure this is a formatting issue, as when I display the DateTime values without a format string (selectedDate.ToString()) then it displays 22/02/2013 00:00:00 correctly. However I need my dates in the format of 22-02-2013 00:00:00.

Any ideas why C# is deciding that my first date is going to be midday, and my second date is going to be 11:59:59?

Comment: Hint: "12:00 am" is "00:00" in 24h format.

Comment: Since the format you ask for is quite popular, I'm surprised there isn't a shortcut for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hh` is the 12 hour clock output.

`HH` is the 24 hour clock output.

You are using the lower-case variant, but not outputting AM/PM values.  This may be the reason for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you are looking for:

```
Console.WriteLine(selectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

For 24 hour format, use `HH` instead of `hh`.

You might want to take a look at the [Custom Date and Time Formats documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).